# Using comparison theorem for integrals to prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The problem states to show that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+5)} dx < \frac{\pi}{10}$ using the fact that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx<\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ and $\sin(x)<x$.

I attempt to set up the inequality as such, but I am having a hard time finding a continuous g(x) on the bounds that is easily integrable so that the inequality holds. Maybe I can find some $c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $g(c) > f(c)$ which would give me a constant that is easily integrable, but I am not sure if this will prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x+5)} dx < \frac{\pi}{10}$. If someone who is more creative than me could help me out that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Note that for $x\in [0\,\pi/2]$, we have

$$0\le \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le 1$$

and

$$0\le \frac{1}{x+5}\le \frac15$$

Comment: ah thank you, I was trying to put the x on top and getting nasty integrals.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.